# Why "overflow: hidden" clears a float?

Tags: css, css-float

The question is simple and short: why does `overflow: hidden;` clear floating? I looked in to the w3 standard documentation and it did not imply anything.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because you establish a new Block Formatting Context when using `overflow` with anything ofther then `visible` ([link to the w3.org specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting)).