# Styling images with CSS in ul li list

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck with a problem and hope stackoverfolw community can help me.

I want to put images with texts in listed order, so I'm using **ul>li** list. My problem begins when I write a paragraph that has less text than the image height, the next paragraph comes just next to it which I don't want. I know it is not well described so I'm attaching a image of it.
[image]
Here is the HTML of that screenshot

```
<ul><li>
<h2>title</h2>
<img src="" class="alignleft" width="200px"/> My text content
</li>
repeat the same again
</ul>
```

css for alignleft is

```
.alignleft{float:left;}
```

If I set the CSS to `.alignleft{float:left;clear:both}` then this problem solves but another problem rises.

Here is a screenshot of listed items styled with .alignleft{float:left;clear:both;}
[image]
The ad on the right has `.alignright{float:right;}` style. Because of the **clear:both** style there is no content with the ads.

Is there any option so that I can achieve both? Like the images below
[image]
[image]

Comment: Post the code, so we can take a better look

Comment: Thanks for your response, I got my answer from @Zeta clear:left did the work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.alignleft{float:left;clear:left}` to clear only the left directed floats.

See also

- [All about floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) (article about using `float` and `clear`)
- [CSS 2.1: 9.5.2 Controlling flow next to floats: the 'clear' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-CSS21-20060411/visuren.html#flow-control):

> **clear:left**: The clearance of the generated box is set to the amount necessary to place the top border edge below the bottom outer edge of any **left-floating boxes** that resulted from elements earlier in the source document.

Comment: Thank you a million!!!!!!!!! I was struggling with this for more than a year and finally got the answer. thanks again. Cheers stackoverflow

Comment: Actually, I think a better solution would be to "self clear" the `li`:s using either `overflow: hidden` or another clearfix method if `overflow: hidden` isn't suitable.

Comment: @powerbuoy can you please explain it a little more like what should be the exact CSS or html?

Comment: All you need to do is set `li {overflow: hidden}`. Parents of floated element won't grow with their children unless the floats are cleared. A few years ago you'd normally add a `<div class="clear"></div>` after floated elements but it's easy to do with just CSS and doesn't require an unnecessary `div`. If you google "clearfix" you'll find several other ways of clearing floats but `overflow: hidden` works cross-browser and requires the least amount of code.
Edit: In this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aWS4h/ you can see the difference between a cleared float (first two `li`s) and none-cleared.

Comment: @Anuj: See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910075/why-overflow-hidden-clears-a-float ;).