# Unable to align buttons in a datatable facet footer

Tags: css, primefaces

Using Primefaces 6.1, I want to add couple of buttons to datatable footer facet. When i use float:left, button moves to left but footer section(div) shrinks.

```
<f:facet name="footer">
    <p:button styleClass="tableButtons" value="Edit" update="msgs"/>
</f:facet>
```

Output with default is:

[image]

Now if I add float:

```
    .tableButtons {
         float: left;
    }
```

The output is:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is a basic CSS problem. The container (in your case the table footer facet div) will be of height 0 when it only has floating childs. You can solve it by setting the `overflow` of the container to `auto` (or `hidden`). The footer facet is classed with `ui-datatable-footer`, so you can use this CSS rule:

```
.ui-datatable-footer {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

See also:

- [Why does 'overflow: auto' clear floats? And why are clear floats needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129343/why-does-overflow-auto-clear-floats-and-why-are-clear-floats-needed)
- [Why "overflow: hidden" clears a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910075/why-overflow-hidden-clears-a-float)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Try to put spacer with `margin.right` or `margin.left`.

```
<p:commandButton id="actionBotton"
                        value="Close"
                        styleClass="classNegative"
                        style="margin-right: 240px;"
                        onclick="dialogEr.hide();"
                        update="dialogEr"
                        />
```